# I edited the .zrshc file - now showing always in terminal like this - how to fix?

Tags: macos, terminal

[image]

I edited that file and now it shows up each time I open the terminal window. How can I fix that or undo that?

Comment: Why did you put `nano ~/.zshrc` in that file?

Comment: @tkausl Probably when OP was trying to edit the zshrc file.

Answer (score 1):

Simply delete the line that says

```
nano ~/.zshrc
```

This line opens that screen during startup.

To delete the line, navigate to it first (such that the cursor is pointing to the first letter of the line `nano ~/.zshrc`.

Then, do the following on your keyboard in order (note that you should press control, **not** the command button):

```
Control+K
Control+S
Control+X
```

Now reopen Terminal and your problem should be solved.